# Smallest python script to print even numbers 0 to 100

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I'm work on a problem which I set myself for fun, which is to create a python script which prints the even numbers from 0 to 100. The challenge is to make the script as small as possible. This is what I have so far:

```
for x in range(0, 101):
    if (x % 2 == 0):
        print x
```

Currently it is 60 bytes. Can anyone think of a way to make it smaller?

---

Edit: `print(*range(2,101,2),sep='\n')` which is 30 bytes. Any smaller?

Comment: `i=2;exec"print i;i+=2;"*50`

Comment: bitpwner's thing has 26 bytes if anyone cares

Comment: @bitpwner [Not all non-competition questions are off topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/14215).

Comment: Ah! My bad. Thanks for the link, was trying to hunt for it.

Comment: This tip is located in the python golfing tips page http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python/1020#1020.

Comment: Is this supposed to start at `0` or `2`? I don't python much, but it looks to me like your two examples do different things. Please correct me if not.

Comment: `print "0 10 100"` (is binary OK?)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage don't forget to golf out the space ;)

Comment: `print(*range(101),sep='\n')` dang, not even my pedantic "you didn't say I couldn't print the numbers in between!" solution isn't as short as the other one :(

Comment: Cannot compete, but for completeness a recursive solution: `f=lambda i:i and"%s\n%i"%(f(i-2),i);print f(100)`

Comment: @Geobits raises a good point; it should be noted that [`0` is even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero).

Answer (score 40):

## Python 2 - 12 characters

```
print 8**999
```

The decimal representation of all even numbers from 0 to 100 can be found in the output:

```
153778990270139647116444851659594064330089236967104214470764753645007350076834118596920008479824182447803706156756475613564110522612279602948135310258168541404369918794480627176627915013920083365328091029969610052054309789461709376676636344651086297099162082351332867728061686056465813162964114500668343488577962834185114919242101638217077550294093097112980059735456387540301162747936045475366317560310988720435512281742591085641505551107966844283901574058972330493685836063965131445246304097593431852972101058022587137885482726523043570690342524474585327775688980689010069001288756281975198668705741000141718184277589376710426738442847382969979234512669279398030637083755270090078676447687796406001053805898105262326290072552249025832780916090265261064205460488458795026145331708830141367124625271312584437671840499845750728447412590406684361326531266896486146862384988911439049971734022314877278748672
```

As a bonus, so can the odd numbers.

Comment: Only problem: It prints the odd numbers and a lot more too.

Comment: @Sieg, even and odd... kinda got all the bases covered, not sure how you find "a lot more" in that. ;)

Comment: Isn't the first time I have a different opinion than other users. I like your answer anyways.

Comment: @paqogomez even numbers 0-100, the odd numbers, and a lot more even numbers >100

Comment: Too curious to avoid asking a dumb Q, why specifically 8*999?

Comment: @0xc0de It's one of the shortest way to obtain a big number that satisfy the property requested. Other examples are `2**952`, `2**964`, `2**975`, `3**553`, `3**612` and other `1231` with the base `< 10` and exponent `< 1000`.

Comment: @OllieFord, thank you for correcting [someone that was wrong on the internet](http://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @paqogomez Isn't that exactly what you did in the first place..? No need to be so defensive, I was just suggesting that may have been what Sieg meant.

Comment: @OllieFord No need to spoil feersum's excellent answer with a drawn out misunderstanding.  I am just having fun. (notice the `:)`) ;-)

Answer (score 31):

## Python 3, 22 (Possibly not allowed)

If the challenge is "to create a python script which prints the even numbers from 0 to 100" and not "to create a python script which prints the even numbers from 0 to 100, *newline separated*", then the shortest solution is:

```
print(*range(0,101,2))
```

Remember, it's very important in code golf not to put any limitations on yourself you don't have to - do what the problem asks, and no more.

Comment: Wouldn't OP's second answer in the edit make you think he wanted it newline separated?

Comment: That's entirely possibly, and is why `possibly not allowed` is in the title. On the other hand, it's also possible that he/she got caught up in matching the output of his initial program, and forgot the initial problem spec. Since I don't know which is the case, I gave this answer.

Answer (score 23):

## Python2 26

```python
i=0;exec"print i;i+=2;"*51
```

independent discovery of @bitpwner's solution

Comment: I get a SyntaxError when I try to run that. Should this answer's top line say "Python 2, 26"?

Comment: +1, you appear to have been 58 seconds faster to post this solution. :)

Answer (score 20):

## Python 2 - 26

```python
i=0;exec"print i;i+=2;"*51
```

Based on the tip on exec with string multiplication found at [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python/1020#1020).

Comment: Should include 0, see Sparr's solution.

Comment: I get a SyntaxError when I try to run that. Should this answer's top line say "Python 2 - 26"?

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, 26 (possibly not allowed)

```python
i=102
while i:i-=2;print i
```

It wasn’t strictly specified, in which order the numbers were to be printed.

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2 - 20 (Possibly not allowed)

This is python 2 specific and probably cheating since it prints the list, but since all numbers end up on the screen:

```
print range(0,101,2)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, 28

```
for i in range(51):print 2*i
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2 in *NIX, 24

```
os.system('seq 0 2 100')
```

If you need to add

```
import os
```

Then the total is 33 characters.

Comment: Clever - This might well be superior in some cases. Is it OS specific?

Comment: @isaacg Very much so, as `os.system` calls a system program.

Comment: If that's allowed, then `os.system('a')`, because I happen to have a program called `a` with the desired behaviour on my system..

Comment: @OllieFord seq is part of gnu coreutils. You don't have quite as much clout.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 29

```
*a,=map(print,range(0,101,2))
```

If you're in Python 2 and happen to have already imported the print function, you don't have to make the iterator object into a list and it becomes 25 characters:

```
map(print,range(0,101,2))
```

I don't know that that's entirely fair though.

Here's another fun idea that works in python 2 or 3. It's a tad longer.

```
def p(i):
    if i+2:p(i-2);print i
p(100)
```

Comment: The Python 3 version can be shortened to `*a,=map(print,range(0,101,2))` using [Extended Iterable Unpacking](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification).

Comment: @flornquake Thanks, I've updated it.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2 - 24

```
0;exec"_+=2;print _;"*50
```

(based on bitpwner and Sparr solution)

In the shell, "_" contains the value of the previously evaluated expression

Comment: You should note that this only works, if pasted into the interactive mode of some Python interpreters (e.g., it does not work in IPython) and not as a script.

Comment: you're right, i forgot to mention that. (btw works in the standard Python console)

Comment: -1 -- The question explicitly mentions a python *script*, which means the code should be written to a *file* and executed. Otherwise a better solution would simply be:`range(0,102,2)` since this would display all the even numbers (plus some commas and two brackets) on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - 20 (questionable)

If isaacg's [space-separated solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36087) is OK, then presumably the normal list formatting is as well:

```
print range(0,101,2)
```

For further rule-twisting, apply SirBraneDamuj's suggestion from the comments:

```
print range(101)
```

and you are at 16. So what if there's some extra garbage separating them?

Answer (score 1):

## Python List Comprehension - 39

This uses a list comprehension, one trick to make it shorter is to multiply the index by 2 rather than going from 0 to 100 and a trailing `if x % 2` check for even.

```
print'\n'.join(`2*x`for x in range(51))
```

Using a map and @isaacg's suggestion it ends up being the same 39 characters:

```
print'\n'.join(map(str,range(0,101,2)))
```

Edit: After separating values by newline it is by far not the shortest.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - OP says `prints the even numbers from 0 to 100`, not just generate them. Also, if you just want the list, `range(0,101,2)` is shorter.

Comment: @isaacg Updated to answer the question, now much longer, needing to embed each value in str() for the join kills it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for the suggestion, didn't know I could do that! Code changed to reflect this new knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use list comprehension (in Python 3.9). < Sorry, I came late but I hope it makes sense.>

```
even_numbers = [x for x in range(100) if x % 2 == 0]
print(even_numbers)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This site is for competitive programming, so we require answers to make a serious attempt at golfing. Make sure to read our [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips?tab=Votes) questions if you want some hints!